# Member Function On Null Wordpress

Tags: php, csv, wordpress

I created a separate PHP script for exporting CSV. When the button is clicked it will direct to the form action where my PHP script is the link. Why when I'll use the $wpdb functions it gets "on null"?

**Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\pwhs.ph\wp-content\themes\pwhs\simple-user-listing\export-csv.php on line 8**

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;

    if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
        ob_end_clean();

        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM wp_diocese");
```

Comment: Is it your full script? Have you required wordpress header files?

Comment: It's just a snippet where the error states but it affects all the wpdb functions actually if I try to comment it, the next function will be declared null. And that's the most top of my custom script file. What are wordpress header files? Maybe that's what I lacked of?

Comment: is this one? `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

 include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
 include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
 include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
 include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';`

Comment: Its already working when I added it. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';


if(isset($_POST['exportBtn'])){
    global $wpdb;
```

Just included the Wordpress headers. Reminded by @u_mulder